# Blade ternary operator without else

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've got a object which has the method `hasATest` that returns a boolean and depending on the value I want a button to be enabled or disabled so I thought of doing something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-detail btn-activate" name="question_id" value="{{$question->id}}" id="activate{{$question->id}}"
    "{{ $question->hasATest() ? disabled : }}"> Activate 
</button>
```

But I don't know what to do about the else. If I remove the `:`, an error occurs:

```
"unexpected ="  ...
```

Plus it's not like there's the opposite for disabled.

Comment: `... ? disabled : enabled}}`?

Comment: if it's enabled nothing has to be written, there's no opposite word for it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ternary operator needs an `else` as you already discovered, you could try some statements like `null` or in this case `""` to return empty values on the `else`.

`{{ ($question->hasATest()) ? "disabled" : "" }}`

Comment: thanks, I put the whole brackets in quotes so when i put "" after the : , it gave me something very weird but this solved it

Answer (score 3):

Just use an empty string for the else part.

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-detail btn-activate" name="question_id" value="{{$question->id}}" id="activate{{$question->id}}"
    {{ $question->hasATest() ? 'disabled' : '' }}> Activate 
</button>
```

I think you could also use an `@if` for it instead of a ternary.

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-detail btn-activate" name="question_id" value="{{$question->id}}" id="activate{{$question->id}}"
    @if($question->hasATest()) disabled @endif> Activate
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in this line:

```
"{{ $question->hasATest() ? disabled : }}"
```

Here is the solution:

```
{{ ($question->hasATest()) ? disabled : 'enable' }}
```

Comment: The `enable` here is not necessary (and might even break stuff), this disable is part of the HTML of the button.

Comment: I just show you the way.You can do this by using empty string.like  this way: {{ ($question->hasATest()) ? disabled : ' ' }}

Answer (score 1):

For those who has to check over the **Non-boolean** variable is there or not

e.g. `$question->test` returns test name (string) then you can use `isset`

```
<td> 
{{ isset($question->test) ? $question->test : __('question.no_test') }}
</td>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me... I was doing something like

<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ isset($params) ? $params->name : '' }}" class="form-control">